# Users home path in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, environment-variables, home

I'm writing a bash-script that will be run as a cron job everyday.  Very basic, I was wanting to change the wallpaper daily.  I have mint-14 with mate.

The thing I'm getting caught up on right now is, I want to have the user's home path detected automatically.  If I don't do this I would have to change it for all other users that run the script.

So far I have tried:

```
homedir=${HOME}/Pictures/daily

mateconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/mate/background/picture_filename $homedir;
```

This doesn't work but,

```
echo $homedir
```

Prints out the correct path?

EDIT:

When I tried `~user` like @vonbrand was suggesting there is no difference.

```
mateconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/mate/background/picture_filename ~user/Pictures/daily;
```

Comment: At least csh, bash use `~user` for the user's home. It is the value of the shell variable `HOME` for each user.

Comment: I've tried to change the above script example to use `~user`  with the `mateconftool-2` command but, its not working?  I've edited my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$HOME is not set in cron, so put this in a script, and let your cron job execute that instead,

(Remember to set the execution bit for that script with chmod +x XX)

```
#!/bin/bash

mateconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/mate/background/picture_filename ~/Pictures/daily
```

Or in your cronjob,

```
HOME="$(getent passwd $USER | awk -F ':' '{print $6}')"
homedir=${HOME}/Pictures/daily
```

Comment: @tijko getent returns colon separated lines, so $6 would be the sixth element, which is your home directory

Comment: Honest question: how portable is it? Is it safe to assume that the user's home directory is the 6th element of the `/etc/password` file for several (most) unices?

Comment: @rahmu hmm, I'm not sure, but the OP runs mint, so that's okay here ...